# Search and replace titles of posts with specific tags

Tags: search, tags, customization

I'd like to do a search and replace of post titles but only affect those with a specific tag.

Eg,

Change post title: This is a new post

to: This is an old post

but on only on posts that have the tag: old

Comment: Please show us what have you tried.

Comment: I looked at some search and replace plugins but couldn't find one where the option was just to change posts with a specific tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Search by tags
$query = new WP_Query( 'tag=old' );

// Then update post titles 
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        //check if title have "a new"
        if(strpos(get_the_title(),'a new') !== false) :

            $post = array(
                'ID'=> get_the_id(),
                'post_title'=> str_replace('a new','an old',get_the_title())
            );

            // Update the post into the database
            wp_update_post( $post );

        endif;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this update all posts with tag=old to the new post title? I only want to update those that have matching title 'This is a new post'. More specifically I only want to change that part of the title. Search and replace 'a new' to 'an old'.

Comment: @Austin i have updated code according to your requirements

Comment: @M Thanks for the updated code. I'm assuming this will change the whole title to "This is an old post"? I only want to change the part 'a new' and replace it with 'an old'. The title I have given is just an example - I have 100's of posts with different titles but common words that I have to replace.

Comment: @Austin i replaced it again :)